# Angular 5 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I have a need to unsubscribe from requests at the time of switching to another route. It seems to me that no matter where the requests are sent (resolvers, components). In my code, the basic sending of requests is performed by the resolvers

```
@Injectable()
  export class RoomsResolve implements Resolve<boolean> {
constructor(
    private roomsService: RoomsService,
    private store: Store<fromRooms.IRoomsState>,
    private resolveRequestUnsubscribeService: ResolveRequestUnsubscribeService
) {}

public resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean {
    this.store.select(fromRooms.getRoomsLoaded).pipe(
        take(1)
    ).subscribe((loaded) => {
        if (!loaded) {
            this.store.dispatch(new fromRooms.GetRoomList({
                requestParams: {
                    lpuId: 204
                },
                requestOptions: {
                    unsubscribe: this.resolveRequestUnsubscribeService.createUnsubscriber(state.url, 'getRoomList')
                }
            }));
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

}

Here we send an action to request data from the back-end service, and create a canceler for the request

The following service is responsible for the operation of the cancelers:

```
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operator/startWith';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart, Router, RouterEvent, 
RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export interface IUnsubscribeCache {
    [name: string]: IUnsubscribeCacheItem;
}

export interface IUnsubscribeCacheItem {
    liveTime: number;
    unsubscribers: {[name: string]: Subject<boolean>};
}

@Injectable()
export class ResolveRequestUnsubscribeService {
   public unsubscribeCache: IUnsubscribeCache = {};
   private unsubscriberLiveTime: number = 60000;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {
    //
    console.log('INIT_ResolveRequestUnsubscribeService');

    this.watchChangeURL();
}

private watchChangeURL(): void {
    this.router.events
        .filter((e) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
        .pairwise()
        .subscribe((event: any[]) => {
            const prevPath: string = event[0].urlAfterRedirects;

            !!prevPath && this.unsubscribeRequests(this.convertPathToUnsubscribersGroupName(prevPath));

            console.log('PREV_URL', event, event[0].urlAfterRedirects);
        });
}

private removeUnfulfilledUnsubscribers(): void {
    const unfulfilledUnsubscribers: string[] = [];

    const now = moment().valueOf();

    _.forIn(this.unsubscribeCache, (value: IUnsubscribeCacheItem, key) => {
        if (value.liveTime + this.unsubscriberLiveTime <= now) {
            unfulfilledUnsubscribers.push(key);
        }
    });

    _.omit(this.unsubscribeCache, unfulfilledUnsubscribers);
}

public createUnsubscriber(path: string, methodName?: string): Subject<boolean> {
    this.removeUnfulfilledUnsubscribers();

    const groupName = this.convertPathToUnsubscribersGroupName(path);

    const unsubscribersGroup = this.unsubscribeCache[groupName];

    !unsubscribersGroup && this.addUnsubscribersGroupToCache(groupName);

    this.unsubscribeCache[groupName].unsubscribers[methodName] = new Subject<boolean>();

    return this.unsubscribeCache[groupName].unsubscribers[methodName];
}

private convertPathToUnsubscribersGroupName(path: string): string {
    return path.replace('/', '_');
}

private addUnsubscribersGroupToCache(groupName: string): void {
    this.unsubscribeCache[groupName] = {
        liveTime: moment().valueOf(),
        unsubscribers: {}
    };
}

private unsubscribeRequests(name: string): void {
    this.removeUnfulfilledUnsubscribers();

    const cache: IUnsubscribeCacheItem = this.unsubscribeCache[name];

    if (cache) {
        if (_.size(cache.unsubscribers) > 0) {
            _.forIn(this.unsubscribeCache[name].unsubscribers, (value: Subject<boolean>, key: string) => {
                value.next(false);
                value.complete();
            });
        }

        _.omit(this.unsubscribeCache, name);
    }
}
```

}

The logic of the work is simple: create a cache, as we go to the route and execute the request, write the cache to the cache and send it to the request, during the transition to another route, we cancel all requests from the previous route.

For http requests implemented wrapper:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Config } from '../../services/config/config';
import { ConfigService } from '../../services/config/config.service';
import { RepositoryError } from './repository-error.model';
import { IRepositoryCachePromise } from './repository-cache-
promise.interface';
import { IRepositoryRequestParams } from './repository-request-
params.interface';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, 
HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';

export class Repository {

    protected config: Config = null;
    protected connectorUrl: string = '';
    protected cachePromisses: IRepositoryCachePromise[] = [];

public constructor(
    protected http: HttpClient,
    protected configService: ConfigService
) {
    //
}

protected request(params: IRepositoryRequestParams): Promise<any> {
    const url: string = this.getConnectorUrl(params.action);

    return this.http.request(
        params.method,
        url,
        {
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization2: params.options.user.getAuthInfo().getAuthToken(),
                lpu_id: params.options.user.getUserInfo().getCurrentHospital().getPlaceID(),
                user_role_id: params.options.user.getUserInfo().getCurrentRole().getID(),
                job_id: params.options.user.getUserInfo().getCurrentJob().getContractID(),
                speciality_code: params.options.user.getUserInfo().getCurrentJob().getID(),
                available_resource_id: params.options.user.getUserInfo().getCurrentJob().getCurrentResource()
                    ? params.options.user.getUserInfo().getCurrentJob().getCurrentResource().getID() : ''
            }
        })
        .takeUntil(params.options.unsubscribe || new Subject<boolean>())
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => {
            const isError: boolean = this.hasError(response);

            return isError ? Promise.reject(response) : response;
        })
        .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => Promise.reject(this.getError(error)));
}

private hasError(response): boolean {
    return !response.success && (response.error
        || (response.warnings && response.warnings.length) || response.errorMessage);
}

private getError(response): RepositoryError {
    return new RepositoryError().parse(response);
}

protected getConnectorUrl(action: string = ''): string {
    if (!this.config) {
        this.getConfig();
    }
    return `${this.config.getApiUrl(this.connectorUrl)}/${action}.api`;
}

private getConfig(): void {
    this.config = this.configService.getConfig();
}

public getCacheKey(url: string, params: any): string {
    params = _.cloneDeep(params);

    if (_.has(params, 'options.user.userInfo')) {
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.contracts;
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.nativeUserInfo;
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.workplaces;
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.roles;
    }

    if (_.has(params, 'options.user.userInfo.currentJob')) {
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.currentJob.resources;
    }

    if (_.has(params, 'options.user.userInfo.currentRole')) {
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.currentRole.allowRights;
        delete params.options.user.userInfo.currentRole.disallowRights;
    }

    if (_.has(params, 'options')) {
        delete params.options.forced;
        delete params.options.cacheLifeTime;
    }

    return url + '?' + JSON.stringify(params);
}
```

}

To cancel the request, I try to use the method `.takeUntil(params.options.unsubscribe || new Subject<boolean>())`, passing in it the canceler from ResolveRequestUnsubscribeService

When I try to cancel a request in the console, I get an error:

> core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isStopped' of object '[object Object]'
>   TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isStopped' of object '[object Object]'

An error causes this line:

> value.complete();

ResolveRequestUnsubscribeService -> unsubscribeRequests

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong

Sorry for my English.

I can not create a workable example